# Alexa Skill S3 missing required key Bucket in params

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make a skill based on [Cake Time Tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/pt-BR/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/get-deeper/tutorials-code-samples/build-an-engaging-alexa-skill/module-3) but whenever I try to invoke my skill I'm facing an error that I don't know why.

This is my invoking function.

```js
    const LaunchRequestHandler = {
       canHandle(handlerInput) {
         console.log(`Can Handle Launch Request ${(Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "LaunchRequest")}`);
         return (
           Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "LaunchRequest"
         );
       },
       handle(handlerInput) {
         const speakOutput =
           "Bem vindo, que série vai assistir hoje?";
           console.log("handling launch request");
           console.log(speakOutput);
         return handlerInput.responseBuilder
           .speak(speakOutput)
           .reprompt(speakOutput)
           .getResponse();
       },
     };
```

It should only prompt a message that's in Portuguese "Bem vindo, que série vai assistir hoje?" but instead it tries to access amazon S3 bucket for some reason and prints this error on console.

```json
~~~~ Error handled: AskSdk.S3PersistenceAdapter Error: Could not read item (amzn1.ask.account.NUMBEROFACCOUNT) from bucket (undefined): Missing required key 'Bucket' in params
    at Object.createAskSdkError (path\MarcaEpisodio\lambda\node_modules\ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter\dist\utils\AskSdkUtils.js:22:17)
    at S3PersistenceAdapter.<anonymous> (path\MarcaEpisodio\lambda\node_modules\ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter\dist\attributes\persistence\S3PersistenceAdapter.js:90:45)
    at step (path\MarcaEpisodio\lambda\node_modules\ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter\dist\attributes\persistence\S3PersistenceAdapter.js:44:23)
    at Object.throw (path\MarcaEpisodio\lambda\node_modules\ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter\dist\attributes\persistence\S3PersistenceAdapter.js:25:53)
    at rejected (path\MarcaEpisodio\lambda\node_modules\ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter\dist\attributes\persistence\S3PersistenceAdapter.js:17:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Skill response
 {
  "type": "SkillResponseSuccessMessage",
  "originalRequestId": "wsds-transport-requestId.v1.IDREQUESTED",
  "version": "1.0",
  "responsePayload": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"response\":{\"outputSpeech\":{\"type\":\"SSML\",\"ssml\":\"<speak>Desculpe, não consegui fazer o que pediu.</speak>\"},\"reprompt\":{\"outputSpeech\":{\"type\":\"SSML\",\"ssml\":\"<speak>Desculpe, não consegui fazer o que pediu.</speak>\"}},\"shouldEndSession\":false},\"userAgent\":\"ask-node/2.10.2 Node/v14.16.0\",\"sessionAttributes\":{}}"
}
----------------------
```

I've removed some ID information from the stack error but I think they're not relevant for the purpose.

The only thing I can think that is calling is when I add S3 adapter in alexa skill builder.

```js
exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
  .withApiClient(new Alexa.DefaultApiClient())
  .withPersistenceAdapter(
    new persistenceAdapter.S3PersistenceAdapter({
      bucketName: process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET,
    })
  )
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    MarcaEpisodioIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler,
    IntentReflectorHandler // make sure IntentReflectorHandler is last so it doesn't override your custom intent handlers
  )
  .addRequestInterceptors(MarcaEpisodioInterceptor)
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

These are my Intents that I've created
[Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoLYk.png)

And this is the function that should handle them.

```js
const Alexa = require("ask-sdk-core");
const persistenceAdapter = require("ask-sdk-s3-persistence-adapter");

const intentName = "MarcaEpisodioIntent";

const MarcaEpisodioIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    console.log("Trying to handle wiht marca episodio intent");
    return (
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) !== "LaunchRequest" &&
      Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === "IntentRequest" &&
      Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === intentName
    );
  },
  async chandle(handlerInput) {
    const serie = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.serie.value;
    const episodio =
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.episodio.value;
    const temporada =
      handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.temporada.value;
    const attributesManager = handlerInput.attributesManager;
    const serieMark = {
      serie: serie,
      episodio: episodio,
      temporada: temporada,
    };
    attributesManager.setPersistentAttributes(serieMark);
    await attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes();

    const speakOutput = `${serie} marcada no episódio ${episodio} da temporada ${temporada}`;

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).getResponse();
  },
};

module.exports = MarcaEpisodioIntentHandler;
```

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> instead it tries to access amazon S3 bucket for some reason

First, your persistence adapter is loaded and configured on each use before your intent handlers' `canHandle` functions are polled. The persistence adapter is then *used* in the `RequestInterceptor` before any of them are polled.

If there's a problem there, it'll break before you ever get to your `LaunchRequestHandler`, which is what is happening.

**Second, are you building an Alexa-hosted skill in the Alexa developer console or are you hosting your own Lambda via AWS?**

Alexa-hosted creates a number of resources for you, including an Amazon S3 bucket and an Amazon DynamoDb table, then ensures the AWS Lambda it creates for you has the necessary role settings and the right information in its environment variables.

If you're hosting your own via AWS, your Lambda will need a role with read/write permissions on your S3 resources and you'll need to set the bucket where you're storing persistent values as an environment variable for your Lambda (or replace the `process.env.S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET` with a string containing the bucket name).

Comment: Thanks for your time answering. I'm using Alexa-hosted. The problem is that my Interceptor process function is causing some error breaking everything? 

Here is my Interceptor function [Interceptor function](https://pastebin.com/DBcsGWd7)

Comment: It's likely not the interceptor. I was able to simulate the error in my old Cake Time, but I didn't get that complete stack trace in CloudWatch or the developer console logs. I would, however, expect it in the debug panel output of Visual Studio Code if I was coding locally and using the Alexa Toolkit for VS Code to test/debug the code.

If that was the case, you'd get this error because you're running the code on your computer instead of in the Lambda and don't have any of the environment variables you need. If that is the case, I have a solution.

Comment: If you're testing in Visual Studio Code, as I suspect, I wrote a persistence adapter for that use case. Code and instructions are in the Alexa Cookbook. https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/tools/LocalPersistence

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem when using visual studio code with S3 for debugging!

I'm still getting an error when trying to use my intent but it doesn't has to do with this error, I should open another topic for that... I'll make some tries by my own, thank you once again!